Question about set. Reflexive, symmetric and transitive
For each of these relations below on the set {1, 2, 3, 4}, determine whether it is
reflexive, symmetric and/or transitive.

{(2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4)}
{(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)}
{(2, 4), (4, 2)}
{(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3), (4, 4)}
{(1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 4)}

My lecturer given answer is this

not reflexive, not symmetric, transitive
reflexive, symmetric, transitive
not reflexive, symmetric, not transitive
reflexive, symmetric, transitive
not reflexive, not symmetric, not transitive

I'm not understand what my lecturer teach. Below is the link how my lecturer teach us.
https://youtu.be/4A7RPNM7Xgc
another video for question 3,4,5 https://youtu.be/mKIrMVkqrTs

another video for question 3,4,5https://youtu.be/mKIrMVkqrTs

A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is reflexive iff for every $a\in A$, there is $(a,a)\in R$. A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is symmetric if the this holds: if $(a,b)\in R$ then $(b,a)\in R$. A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is transitive if this holds: if $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in R$ then $(a,c)\in R$.


A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is reflexive iff for every $a\in A$, there is $(a,a)\in R$.
For example, relation 1 is not reflexive because $(1,1),(4,4)\notin R_1$. But 2 is reflexive because $R_2$ contains $(a,a)$ for all $a$ in $A$.

A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is symmetric if the this holds: if $(a,b)\in R$ then $(b,a)\in R$. Note that if neither $(a,b)$ nor $(b,a)$ belong to $R$ the relation may still be symmetric because there is nothing to invalidate.
For example, 3 is symmetric but 5 is not because $(4,1)\notin R_5$. $(4,1)\notin R_3$ either but it doesn't matter since $(1,4)\notin R_3$ too.

A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is transitive if this holds: if $(a,b)\in R$ and $(b,c)\in R$ then $(a,c)\in R$. Once again, if $(a,b)\notin R$ or $(b,c)\notin R$, then you need not check for $(a,c)$. Verify for all relations.

But why my lecturer say question 4 is reflexive, symmetric, transitive? is it true?

@TanTianXiang your approach should be to see if the condition fails instead of proving the condition holds. the minute it fails, you say it's not true. and if it doesn't fail but the elements are exhausted then you can say the properties hold.

@TanTianXiang for reflexivity you check for $(a,a)$ for $a=1,2,3,4$. doesn't fail. For symmetry, you check for $(a,b)$ if $(b,a)$ is there but since all elements are of form $(a,a)$ the condition doesn't fail. similarly for transitivity. The answers you mentioned are correct.
